# Object Annotation in images with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to develop an automatic(or semi-automatic) image annotator for my final year project with `OpenCV`. I have been studying many OpenCV resources and have come across `cascade classification` for training and detection purposes. I understood that part, and also tried the Face Detection tutorial provided with OpenCV. So, now I know how to train and detect objects.

However, I still cannot understand how can I annotate objects present in the image?

For example, the system will show that this is an object, but I want the system to show that it is a ball. How can i accomplish that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: cascade classification is a *detection* task(thing or not). any cascade can only detect the *1* type it was trained on. what you're up to sounds more like a *recognition* one (multiple object classes), so i doubt, you'll get far with the cascade approch

Comment: but the Face Detection demo given with OpenCV detects both Face and Eyes. So, I assumed it can detect multiple objects. Am I wrong?

Comment: that's using 2 cascades, one for faces, another for eyes. works with small number of classes, but does not scale to bigger numbers

Comment: ohh..then what do you suggest I should do?

Answer (score 1):

One binary classificator (detector) can separate objects by two classes:

positive - the object type classifier was trained for,

and negative - all others.

If you need detect several distinguished classes you should use one detector for each class, or you can train multiclass classifier ("one vs all" type of classifiers for example), but it usually works slower and with less accuracy (because detector better search for similar objects). You can also take a look at convolutional networks (by [Yann LeCun](http://yann.lecun.com/)).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But several, let's say 5, classifiers will **detect** 5 different types of objects right? I want _annotation_ as well. For example, if 3 of the 5 objects I trained the system for are present in the image, I also want the system to tell which objects are they. How can i accomplish something like that?

Comment: If object detected by detector1 then it belongs to calss1, if object detected by detector2 then it belongs to class2, and so on. You can know the class of object looking which detector found this object.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very hard task. I suggest simplifying it by using latent SVM detector and limiting yourself to the models it supplies:
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/latent_svm.html